# Error parsing XML:no element found - How can I fix this bug?

Tags: android, gridview

Please help me fix these bugs, I was making a app these errors are coming while running this app,
[image]

CODE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.shivamx.test_splash.Home_test"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="@color/backgroundcolor">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="64dp"
                    android:layout_height="64dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/circle_bg_green"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_inbox_black_24dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="Engineering"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:background="@color/lightgray">

                </View>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Study Material"
                    android:textColor="@color/darkgrey"

                    />

            </LinearLayout>


        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="64dp"
                    android:layout_height="64dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/circle_bg_yelow"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_bba_black_24dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="BBA"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:background="@color/lightgray">

                </View>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Study Material"
                    android:textColor="@color/darkgrey"

                    />

            </LinearLayout>


        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>





    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="64dp"
                    android:layout_height="64dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/circle_bg_pink"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_bsc_black_24dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="BSc"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:background="@color/lightgray">

                </View>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Study Material"
                    android:textColor="@color/darkgrey"

                    />

            </LinearLayout>


        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="64dp"
                    android:layout_height="64dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/circle_bg_purple"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_llb_black_24dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="LLB"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:background="@color/lightgray">

                </View>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Study Material"
                    android:textColor="@color/darkgrey"

                    />

            </LinearLayout>


        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>






    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="64dp"
                    android:layout_height="64dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/circle_blue_aboutme"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_about_me_box_black_24dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="About Me"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:background="@color/lightgray">

                </View>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="About The Creator"
                    android:textColor="@color/darkgrey"

                    />

            </LinearLayout>


        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>



</LinearLayout>
```

These files exist in the folder res/layouts. Still error is there. What should i do?
Please tell fast.

Comment: share your activity_home_test.xml file with question

Comment: Don't post code images. And don't post error images.

Comment: Verify  tools:context="com.example.shivamx.test_splash.Home_test" is correct one. and verify all resources exists or not

Comment: `Please tell fast.` Why do you think that your question is so urgent for us? Hurrying who is going to help you (for free, in their spare time) is so irritating.

Answer (score 2):

from the looks of it `activity_home_test.xml` does not exist in your `res/layout/` directory.

Comment: the files are there bro.

Comment: @ShivamPokhriyal than share it with question

Comment: Post the contents of `activity_home_test.xml`

Comment: please check bro @Nate

Comment: @ShivamPokhriyal You just forgot to close your parent </LinearLayout> correct it

Comment: As others have said </LinearLayout> at the end.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is correct You just forgot to close your parent **`<LinearLayout>`** correct it

Just close your parent `</LinearLayout>` like below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.shivamx.test_splash.Home_test"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="@color/backgroundcolor">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="64dp"
                    android:layout_height="64dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/circle_bg_green"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_inbox_black_24dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="Engineering"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:background="@color/lightgray">

                </View>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Study Material"
                    android:textColor="@color/darkgrey"

                    />

            </LinearLayout>


        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="64dp"
                    android:layout_height="64dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/circle_bg_yelow"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_bba_black_24dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="BBA"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:background="@color/lightgray">

                </View>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Study Material"
                    android:textColor="@color/darkgrey"

                    />

            </LinearLayout>


        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>





    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="64dp"
                    android:layout_height="64dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/circle_bg_pink"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_bsc_black_24dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="BSc"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:background="@color/lightgray">

                </View>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Study Material"
                    android:textColor="@color/darkgrey"

                    />

            </LinearLayout>


        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="64dp"
                    android:layout_height="64dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/circle_bg_purple"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_llb_black_24dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="LLB"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:background="@color/lightgray">

                </View>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Study Material"
                    android:textColor="@color/darkgrey"

                    />

            </LinearLayout>


        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>






    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="64dp"
                    android:layout_height="64dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/circle_blue_aboutme"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_about_me_box_black_24dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="About Me"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:background="@color/lightgray">

                </View>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="About The Creator"
                    android:textColor="@color/darkgrey"

                    />

            </LinearLayout>


        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>



    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have not declare root `layout element` in your `XML` or not close root element. so might you getting error. format should like below.

```
<rootelement>
   <subelement>
          .......
   </subelemnt>
</rootelement>
```

for example:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.divyesh.friendfinder.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/Hint"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/editTextusername"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editTextusername"
        android:hint="Enter second user lat"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/editTextlat"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editTextlat"
        android:hint="Enter second user long"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/editTextlong"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textinformssssss"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Click Button bellow and Start Service"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/subbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="genrate location"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textinformssssss"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```